# How to pass component reference in Input with *ngIf Angular2

Tags: angular

I have 2 sibling components in Angular2:

```
<test1 *ngIf="data"  [data] = "makes" #test1R></formModel>
<testing *ngIf="data" [test1Ref]="test1R"></testing>
```

Component "Testing" has a function that call a function of test1 Component:

```
export class Testing{

    @Input() test1Ref: test1Component;
    constructor() { }

    testFunction($event){
        this.test1Ref.hello();
    }
```

My problem is that `this.test1Ref` is undefined, because test1 component has *ngIf (`<test1 *ngIf="data"`) , 

but without *ngIf I have an error in test1 component for input value (`[data] = "makes"`). 
How can I pass component reference with *ngIf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't. You'll have to hide the component if `!data` , that way your local variable #test1R will still be set.

```
<test1 [hidden]="!data" [data]="makes" #test1R></test1>
```

Then null check inside test1 in `ngOnInit()` to avoid the exception.

If you can only execute certain code once data is set, do it like this:

Declare data as an Input inside your test1 component:

```
export class Test1 {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

By declaring it as an `@Input` everytime the value changes, Angular will call ngOnChanges, so now you can do this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes['data'] && changes['data'].currentValue) {
    //Do something once data is set.
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I understand, I don't like because if I retrieve data with async call , check if data exists in ngInit is always useless..so I have to handle some event?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to handle null checking for async.

Comment: No probs :-) have fun!